# Python linter in VS-Code: raising error when method has a type annotation but no return statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter

I am trying to enable in my linter the style-error (if this is the most suitable name) that should arise when a function has a type hint but no return statement. For instance:

```
def do_stuff() -> int:
    a = 2
    # this function expect at the very least something to be returned
    # but no return statement is provided
```

I have looked at pylint, mypy and flake8 documentation but they seem to not support such error.
Also, is there a linter capable of arising a type-error, that is, the function is supposed to return an `int` but is actually returning a `str`. For instance:

```
def do_stuff() -> int:
    a = 2
    return 'abc'
    # this function expect a int value to be returned
    # but str value is returned instead
```

I am using VSCode. I know that this is possible in PyCharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) supports this kind of static type checks out of the box by using [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) under the hood.

I am not sure if Pylint already supports the >Python 3.6 style of static typing.
The [documentation here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/extensions.html) suggests that it uses / used an extra extension module that parses the docstrings of the function for the return parameter.

Comment: Do I need to enable it as linter as well?

Comment: I don't think so. At least my settings don't reflect the fact, I still have pylint set there.
You just have to enable it as language server when prompted: ```Select Yes when prompted to make Pylance the default language server. ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a linter can do this! However, for both cases, and especially for your latter desire (raise complaints if you return the wrong type), I think you don't really want a linter, you want an actual static typechecker.

The most common implementation is called `mypy`, but Google also provides a less-strict typechecker called `ptype` - that might be a better fit for a codebase that isn't (yet) highly disciplined about type annotations.